# Set an alternative image with graphicImage primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

this is the bean that i used to upload and set an alternative image.

Bean

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
       byte[] photo=IOUtils.toByteArray(event.getFile().getInputstream());
       System.out.println("OK");
       System.out.println(photo);
       eleve.setPhoto(photo);
       FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Reussie!",  event.getFile().getFileName() + " uploaded!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
          }


public StreamedContent getImageEleve()  {
                Map<String, String> parametres=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String idEleve=parametres.get("id_Eleve");

        if(idEleve!=null) {
            Eleve el=eleveService.getEleve(Long.parseLong(idEleve));
           return el.getImagem();
        }
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getResourceAsStream("/css/images/boy.png"));
            }
```

primefaces

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{eleveMB.imageEleve}" cache="false" style="width:100px; height:100px; vertical-align: middle">
            <f:param name="id_Eleve" value="#{eleve.id}"></f:param>
            </p:graphicImage>

<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">

                        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{eleveMB.upload}"
                            update=":form:graphic" auto="true" />
                        <br></br>
                        <p:graphicImage id="graphic" value="#{eleveMB.eleve.imagem}"
                            cache="false" style="width:300px; height:300px"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
```

The uploading is Okay, but I want set an alternative image if I don't upload an image. 
Thank you.

Comment: Then just set a 'default image' and override this if something is uploaded...

Comment: I tried to set default image by `new DefaultStreamedContent(FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getResourceAsStream("/css/images/boy.png"));` But it don't work.

Comment: ok, sorry, missed that in your code. But then my next comment is: "did not work"  is not very useful to work with. Does it start WW-III instead of showing the image? And if you remove all upload code etc... it is like you have a fixed image. Does that work? If not, try to find generic Q/A in stackoverflow about this more generic problem

Comment: Try telling about the observed problem as if you are the developer of the application, not as if you're the enduser of the application. For example, instead of unhelpfully saying "it doesn't work, why does it not work?", say e.g. "it threw null pointer exception because the getResourceAsStream() returned null, why did it return null?"

Comment: thank you for your relevant comments, you are quite right.So I removed upload code from the method getImageEleve(), in result , alternative image is displayed.

Comment: It is always a bad idea to perform business logic in a getter because it usually gets called more times so the same thing is done often